# Python implementation of Marginal Maximum Likelihood estimate based 2-PL Dichotomous IRT

Tags: python, maximum-likelihood, item-response-theory, mirt

I am looking for implementations of simple **Marginal Maximum Likelihood Estimate** based 2-PL IRT Item estimation in **Python**. Any relevant Python libraries that do this (similar to snowIRT module in Jamovi)? I have looked into `py-irt` and it seems to do a Variational Inference based estimate of the parameters. I wanted something very simple for **Marginal** MLE and a dichotomous 2-PL IRT.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.